# How to interpret "forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault" output?

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran

My application failed with the following error:

```
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
TBFsolver          0000000000512AF3  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libpthread-2.22.s  00007FBFC99AAC10  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
TBFsolver          00000000004B463A  vofmod_mp_compute        1600  VOF.f90
TBFsolver          00000000004B3ECD  vofmod_mp_compute        1506  VOF.f90
TBFsolver          00000000004B0917  vofmod_mp_offset_         879  VOF.f90
TBFsolver          00000000004AE333  vofmod_mp_solvevo         754  VOF.f90
libiomp5.so        00007FBFC9CDED43  __kmp_invoke_micr     Unknown  Unknown
libiomp5.so        00007FBFC9C6ED65  __kmp_fork_call       Unknown  Unknown
libiomp5.so        00007FBFC9C2EC60  __kmpc_fork_call      Unknown  Unknown
TBFsolver          00000000004AD6EC  vofmod_mp_solvevo         700  VOF.f90
TBFsolver          00000000004F8BCA  MAIN__                     77  main.f90
TBFsolver          0000000000406222  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.22.so       00007FBFC7DB1725  __libc_start_main     Unknown  Unknown
TBFsolver          0000000000406129  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

I did not find a clear explanation of how to interpret the lines given to me in the error file. It would be great if somebody could give me a clue whether one of the lines can help me to find my error.

Edit: in line 1600 of VOF.f90 there is:

```
delta(dir)=vel*rdt
```

Comment: No I know what a seg fault is, however I am not sure how to interpret what the above output says.

Comment: You've got all the useful information out of the above - the segfault occurs at line 1600 of VOF.f90. I suspetc dir is out of the range of bounds for the array delta. If you haven't already recompile with bounds checking enabled and see what it tells you - to be honest whenever you got a segfault this should be your first course of action.

Comment: That was also my first assumption, but the code has worked for days and this part of the code has been passed thousands of times without any problem... but thanks.

Comment: @tre95 Rhat does not mean anythiing. Enable your compiler checks, roll up your sleeves and start debugging using the backtrace you have. You have the line number.

Comment: Also, the edit with the line is useless. If you want anything more, you *must* supply a real [mcve] that you tested with the debugging compiler flags and verified that it stil crashes. The first to check is the value of the array index and the ranges of the array.